# Is it viable for a highly elliptic orbit to rotate around one of its foci?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, space, physics, gravity

I was experimenting with various star system designs with a gravity simulator, and one of the patterns I ended up with is best described as a planet with a very elongated elliptic orbit that itself rotates around an axis located at/near one of the orbit's foci. This gif illustrates it pretty accurately:

[image: Orbit]

I believe I created this by simulating a low-mass body moving near the large-mass body and falling into orbit, but at a slight angle so as to create an offset that shifted the orbit every revolution. Would this be possible with an actual planet and a star? If so, would there be any noteworthy side effects aside from the obvious (e.g. having extremely varying climates at different points during the year)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only is this possible, it happens with real planets including the Earth.  It is called [Apsidal precession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession).  This cycle and a similar cycle relating to the Earth's axis Axial precession are known as the [Milankovitch cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles).  They are believed to be a factor in long-term climate changes including ice ages, though how significant they are is not well understood.  If a planet had a large eccentricity (like Mercury or, taken to an extreme, your example), the effects of that would dwarf the effects from the precessions and likely make the planet uninhabitable.

Comment: [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/cosmology-and-astronomy/earth-history-topic/earth-title-topic/v/apsidal-precession-perihelion-precession-and-milankovitch-cycles) is a Khan Academy video discussing these topics (I couldn't put it in my answer because I am restricted to 2 links).

Comment: It depends how far, and for how long the planet is out of the habitable zone.  Place it around a star with a wide habitable zone, and perhaps it might be okay.